# Sync Framework: Get description for table

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

At a step of provisioning the databases for synchronization, it is possible

to Get Descryptions For Tables including the triggers in that table ?

If yes, 
does anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. the GetDescriptionForTable is simply for retrieving the structure of the table for purposes of data synchronization. Sync Fx doesnt sync schemas so it doesnt care about the other database objects such as triggers, views, stored procs, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, theres no other way to get the remote database objects such as triggers, etc ?

Comment: As I have mentioned, Sync Fx doesn't care about them. You have to code it yourself or script out the database and pre-create the objects rather than relying on Sync Fx provisioning.